# I keep getting Error: "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, pycharm, file-not-found, filenotfounderror

I have a program where I want to access a text file from my program. Even though the code is correct and the file has been created in the same directory, PyCharm is refusing to access it. I want to know how to fix this error.

I want to access a text file "data.txt" from my program called "bonus11". Even though the code is correct and the file has been created in the same directory, the program cannot open it.
I have already tried pasting the entire file path.

```
    def get_average():
        with open("data.txt.py", 'r') as file:
            data = file.readlines()
        return data
    
    
    average = get_average()
    print(average)
```

This is code with the file and directory:
[image: This is code with the file and directory]

I want to know how to access the file named `data.txt` from the `bonus11`.
I would be thankful for any changes to the code

Comment: You have 2 problems: 1) wrong path to file `data.txt.py` cause this file is inside directory `files` 2) IMO file `data.txt.py` should have `.txt` extension instead of `.py`

Comment: _I want to know how to access the file_ Use the full pathname to the file.  When you just call `open("data.txt.py", 'r')`, it assumes the file is in the current directory.  But it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The path is incorrect, it should be `with open("./files/data.txt.py", 'r') as file:`